# Unusual white screen fading with lines on Monitor

Tags: display, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, external-display, displayport

Suddenly after updating my linux distro, my monitor is broken now. It is behaving strange. It's showing white screen on boot, with a slow graphics and fading effect. White line are also visible on screen. Please have a look on attached video.
I thought it is problem with distro but it remains same even if I change my CPU. Even the bios logo and "No Signal" text by monitor itself is affected.

What could be the reasons? What should I do?

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ijquUxmqqBhFuf6hIjLMJtmjNa8F3SjB

Comment: Do you have another computer that you can test the monitor on?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it. But its same there.

Comment: How old is the monitor? It might just be coincidence that it broke at the same time you performed the OS update. Has it made any unusual noises, like popping or crackling?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, it's not abnormally cold or hot where you're using this PC, is it?

Comment: I don't remember accurately. But its been around 5 years.

Comment: Its normal room temperature here. Around 20 at day te and 12 at night, winters in India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have tested this monitor on another computer, then the issue lies with the monitor. Slow fading like you have is a symptom of a defective LVDS communication between the electronics and the LCD itself. As for the reasons:

- Did you check your cables and connectors for any damage?
- Has the monitor been moved during your update?
- Any recent drop or knocking on it?
- Did you check for any firmware update for this monitor? It is possible the internal firmware is corrupted.

If the monitor was moved and possibly hit, then the LCD panel is defective. The price for replacing it is usually higher than a new monitor, so I suggest buying a new or used monitor.

Comment: I've checked cable properly. Even replaced it with new. It is still same. No I haven't moved or hit it.  I don't know about firmware but I never did anything about it. Anyways thank you.

Comment: Only thing left would be firmware. To udpate the firmware, you need to go to the monitor's manufacturer website. They will give you a file to install if available. Though I highly doubt this will solve the issue.

Comment: I was figure out what happened. May be firmware. Anyways thanks for helping. I'll get a new one.